# Cannot set g++ compiler for CMake

Tags: c++, c++11, cmake, g++, clang++

I want to use g++ compiler in my CPP project. So I setup Cmake file like this:

```html
set(CMAKE_CXX_COMPILER "/usr/local/bin/g++")

project(GatewayTest LANGUAGES C CXX)
...
```

But when error still be shown with Clang. I ran on MacOS Sierra.
The error is:

clang: error: linker command failed with exit code 1 (use -v to see invocation).
Am i wrong with this setting?

Comment: hard to say without the rest of the file .... you want to compile with clang and link with g++ ??? or do you want to compile with g++ ?

Comment: Just compile with g++. But i don't know why the console show clang error

Comment: Both code and error message contains very little information for suggest something. Provide [mcve].

Answer (score 3):

Don't try to set the compiler from inside the `CMakeLists.txt`.

The idea behind this flag is that you give *the user* the opportunity to specify which compiler to use. This makes sense, as the user will know which machine they are going to build on, so they should know where to find the compiler. It does *not* make sense to make this information part of the build script, as the build script is, in principle, supposed to be portable to any machine and compiler.

If your project requires a specific compiler to be built correctly, you can *inspect* the variables like `CMAKE_CXX_COMPILER` and raise a diagnostic if they do not contain what you expect, but you should never write to those variables.

If you do want to scriptify compiler detection, you can either wrap the call to CMake in a shell script that sets the variables used for compiler detection or use a [toolchain file](https://cmake.org/cmake/help/v3.10/manual/cmake-toolchains.7.html#cmake-toolchains-7) for configuring CMake.

Comment: Good answer. Let me check following your guide

Answer (score -2):

```html
set(CMAKE_C_COMPILER "clang")
set(CMAKE_CXX_COMPILER "clang++")
project(GatewayTest LANGUAGES C CXX)
...
```